# Declare an Objective-C static method that can be called without a class instance?

Tags: objective-c

How do you declare an Objective-C static method that can be called without a class instance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put a `+` instead of the usual `-` in front of your method definition.

Comment: Your answer is best ones to this question but could you say how can define static method in objective-c?

Comment: user can not create static method as objective c does not support static method concept. static methods are supported in JAva or c++ languages.